# Why is one TimerTask slowing down another?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have got a Timer Task, which updates all player positions:

```
public void run(){
    updateWatcher = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            update(0.1);
        }
    };

    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateWatcher, 5, 5);
}
```

And I also have another TimerTask right under that one, which updates all projectile positions:

```
UpdateWatcher = new TimerTask() { //Different variable. Note the capital U.
        public void run() {
            for (Bullet b : bullets){
                b.update();
            }
        }
    };
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(UpdateWatcher, 5, 5);
}
```

However, the second TimerTask is slowing down the first one. If I delete the iteration, like this:

```
UpdateWatcher = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

        }
    };
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(UpdateWatcher, 5, 5);
}
```

The player moves at the correct speed. However, as soon as I re-add the code (using Eclipse de-bugging to add it live), the delayed task executes a lot less often, causing players to be moving more than 10 times slower than usual.

What could be causing this, and how could I fix it?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what's in the `update` methods and what kind of data structures you are using.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I really doubt you want a huge dump of my large and probably inefficient code. The point is, the bullet's update method has nothing to do with anything else. I see no reason why one TimerTask which is in a *completely separate thread* is affecting another one.

Comment: Depends on the `update` logic and the synchronisation if any.

Comment: Well, usually the players and the bullets in a game exist in the same world, which means that they have some data shared, which means access to that data has to be synchronized, which means that threads working on them will be affecting each other. But without a proper [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this is all just hot air (or hot silicone).

Comment: Yes, but if I give each `Bullet` it's own thread, the problem disappears. The `Bullet` has absolutely no way it is synchronizing or even using anything from the `Players` class, excluding a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which, since it's designed for concurrency, isn't going to hold up anything. I unfortunately don't have the time for an MCVE, but is there anything I may not be aware of about TimerTasks which may be causing one task to hold up another?